# Encoding Error in SAS

Tags: sas

I am getting the following error while running a SAS code:

> Error: File XXX.xxx cannot be updated because its encoding does not match the session encoding or the file is in a format native to another host, such as WINDOWS_64

The dataset XXX.xxx is being made in the same code; how can the encodings be different?

I have no clue how to fix it. Any help will be good.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some of your code so that we can see what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following properties of your tables:

```
proc sql;
create table my_tables as
select libname, memname, datarep, datarepname, encoding
 from dictionary.tables where libname='DATA'
;
quit;
```

This error is typical in situations where you try to update some SAS file that wascreated by another computer with different OS or different bits (32 vs 64 bit) of the OS or of SAS installed.

So if you have e.g. Windows 32bit and the SAS file was created by a 64bit SAS, you will have to use `OUTREP` option to specify correct data representation like this:

```
libname lib1 "C:\path..." outrep='WINDOWS_64';
```

The option is also available as a dataset option, usefull e.g. when you have a mix of versions of SAS files in a single directory/library.

Comment: I understand that, but the thing is I am making the dataset in the same code. Just 2-3 lines before I start updating that. How can the encoding be different for that?

Comment: What about the rest of  library, other datasets? Check datarepname with my first code sample. Can you post your code?